# Calling arrays to be calculated by function

Tags: python, numpy, h5py

I have two functions: the "main" one, which runs the scripts and creates an H5-file to store data and one which provides the data by doing calculations between the two arrays I give it. How do I give the math function my arrays properly and have it calculate the data to my H5 file? I'm having trouble calling the aforementioned function in my math one.

How I create the H5 file:

```
with h5py.File('calculations.h5', 'w') as hf:
        if not hf.__contains__(pre):
            hf.create_group(pre)
        if not hf[pre].__contains__('array_one'):
            hf[pre].create_group('array_one')
        if not hf[pre].__contains__('array_two'):
            hf[pre].create_group('array_two')
        for dim in aver.__dict__.keys():
            if not dim == 't':
                for key in aver.__getattribute__(pre).__dict__.keys():
                    if not hf[pre]['array_one'].__contains__(dim):
                        hf[pre]['array_one'].create_group(dim)
                    if not hf[pre]['array_one'][dim].__contains__(key[:-2]):
                        hf[pre]['array_one'][dim].create_dataset(key[:-2].lower(),
                        data=aver.__getattribute__(dim).__getattribute__(key))
                    if not hf[pre]['array_two'].__contains__(dim):
                        hf[pre]['array_two'].create_group(dim)
                    if not hf[pre]['array_two'][dim].__contains__(key[:-2]):
                        hf[pre]['array_two'][dim].create_dataset(key[:-2].lower(),
                        data=calc.__getattribute__(key[:-2].lower()))
                    arrone = hf[pre]['array_one'][dim]
                    arrtwo = hf[pre]['array_two'][dim]
        if relerr:
            if not hf[pre].__contains__('relerrors'):
                hf[pre].create_group('relerrors')
            for dim in hf[pre]['array_one'].keys():
                if not hf[pre]['relerrors'].__contains__(dim):
                    hf[pre]['relerrors'].create_group(dim)
                for key in hf[pre]['array_one'][dim].keys():
                    reler = relerror(arrone,arrtwo)
                    hf[pre]['relerrors'][dim].create_dataset(key+"_relerror",data=reler)
```

My math function:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import norm
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error as mae

def relerror(arrone,arrtwo,relerr=True):
relone=arrone.copy()
reltwo=arrtwo.copy()
atmp=np.ma.array(arrtwo)
atmp[atmp==0]=np.ma.masked
if relerr:
    relone[atmp.mask==True] = arrone[atmp.mask==True]
    relone[atmp.mask==False] = arrone[atmp.mask==False]/np.abs(arrtwo[atmp.mask==False])
    reltwo[atmp.mask==False] = arrtwo[atmp.mask==False]/np.abs(arrtwo[atmp.mask==False])
return mae(relone, reltwo)
```

EDIT: Adding `[()]` as @kcw78 proposed, and `[key[:-2].lower()][()]` now calls the arrays in a proper way.

Comment: if you really want help you need to be specific about the problem(s), not this vague 'having problems'

Comment: True. I've elaborated on my problem under Michael S's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer posted by @Micheal S **should** address your question about calling a function and returning the values.

Your newest question has to do with the way you are reading the HDF5 dataset. The way you access the dataset returns a h5py dataset object: `arrone = hf[pre]['array_one'][dim]`. Dataset objects "behave like" numpy arrays in many ways. However in your case, you need an array. To do this, add `[()]`, like this: `arrone = hf[pre]['array_one'][dim][()]` or
`arrone = hf[f'{pre}/array_one/{dim}'][()]` (to use a f-string to define the path)

The rest of this answer addresses h5py usage to create the HDF5 file. You have **a lot** of code to check group names and create the ones that don't exist. You don't need to do that -- use `require_group()` instead. It works like this:

`hf.require_group(f'{pre}/array_one')` and the same for `array_two` and `dim` groups.

There is also a `require_dataset()` function to do the same for datasets.

Next, you don't need to call the dunder `__contains__` method. Instead, use `if 'array_one' not in hf:`.

Finally, it's not clear what you are trying to do with `__getattribute__()`. If you are trying to get a group or dataset attribute, there is an easier way with the `.attr()` method. It uses the same dictionary syntax.

This is my attempt to pull all of this together:
Improved method to create the H5 file:

```
with h5py.File('calculations.h5', 'w') as hf:
        hf.require_group(f'{pre}/array_one')
        hf.require_group(f'{pre}/array_two')
        for dim in aver.keys():  # aver undefined: assumes this is a group object
            if not dim == 't':
                for key in aver.__getattribute__(pre).__dict__.keys():
                    hf[pre]['array_one'].require_group(dim)
                    if  key[:-2] not in hf[pre]['array_one'][dim]:
                        hf[pre]['array_one'][dim].create_dataset(key[:-2].lower(),
                        data=aver.__getattribute__(dim).__getattribute__(key))
                    hf[pre]['array_two'].require_group(dim)
                    if key[:-2] not in hf[pre]['array_two'][dim]:
                        hf[pre]['array_two'][dim].create_dataset(key[:-2].lower(),
                        data=calc.__getattribute__(key[:-2].lower()))
                    arrone = hf[pre]['array_one'][dim][:]
                    arrtwo = hf[pre]['array_two'][dim][:]
        if relerr:
            hf[pre].require_group('relerrors')
            for dim in hf[pre]['array_one'].keys():
                hf[pre]['relerrors'].require_group(dim)
                for key in hf[pre]['array_one'][dim].keys():
                    reler = relerror(arrone,arrtwo)
                    hf[pre]['relerrors'][dim].create_dataset(key+"_relerror",data=reler)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was going to comment this but it was a bit too long.

Is this code indented correctly? If not, fix it. Then, after you define your function, you have to call it:

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import norm
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error as mae

################################################################################# 
#Your h5py code here, it's too long and I don't want to include it in the answer#
################################################################################# 

def relerror(arrone,arrtwo,relerr):
    relone=arrone.copy()
    reltwo=arrtwo.copy()
    atmp=np.ma.array(arrtwo)
    atmp[atmp==0]=np.ma.masked
    if relerr:
        relone[atmp.mask==True] = arrone[atmp.mask==True]
        relone[atmp.mask==False] = arrone[atmp.mask==False]/np.abs(arrtwo[atmp.mask==False])
        reltwo[atmp.mask==False] = arrtwo[atmp.mask==False]/np.abs(arrtwo[atmp.mask==False])
    return mae(relone, reltwo)

maeResult = relerror(arrone, arrtwo, True)
print(maeResult)
```

Comment: My other function should be doing what you propose in 
`reler = relerror(arrone,arrtwo)
                    hf[pre]['relerrors'][dim].create_dataset(key+"_relerror",data=reler)`

Error which I'm being given now is `TypeError: copy() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'source' and 'dest'` which tells me that I'm not setting them up correctly in the math funct. 
I'm copying: `arrone = hf[pre]['array_one'][dim] arrtwo = hf[pre]['array_two'][dim]` in `relone=arrone.copy() reltwo=arrtwo.copy()` to create masked arrays for calculation. How do I get around this?

Comment: @eulinean, your question above has to do with the way you are reading the HDF5 dataset. You are returning a h5py object, and you need a numpy array. I updated my answer to show how to do this.

Comment: @kcw78, Thanks for the syntax improvements.

Comment: @eulinean, did my answer with the method to read datasets as arrays solve your problem? If so, please accept so others know the solution. If not, please update question to give current status.

Comment: @kcw78, I've edited the post with my current solution. However, on your proposed improvements and the usage of f-strings, I'm getting the error: `name 'array_one' is not defined` on `hf.require_group(f'pre/{array_one}')`.

Comment: Yeah, I have the `{}` in the wrong place. They are supposed to be for variables. I will fix.